# Why Euler relation $\;e^{(ix)}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)\;$ can be writen as $\;e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

As I know,
$$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+...$$
$$\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+x^4/4!...$$
$$\sin(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!...$$
so that
$$e^{ix}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)$$
Then why is the following true? $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

Comment: No, $e^{ix} = \cosh (ix) + \sinh (ix)$, not $\cos (ix) + \sin (ix)$.

Comment: Also, $e^x \neq \sin(x) + \cos(x)$...

Comment: @Starterry: Review http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula

Comment: Guys, I'm not aware of the edit history of this problem, but aren't 3 downvotes a little harsh?

Comment: I see, it's my big problem. This question is quitly wrong itself. Thank u guys.

Comment: Don't sweat it, Starterry! You're welcome, on behalf of those of us who try to be helpful.

Comment: @Doc Unfounded, IMO. The original was not properly LaTeXed, which was the only thing wrong with it$^1$. Nothing calling for a downvote. ($^1$ I'm not talking about the mathematical content, the OP mixed up two identities and thus got a wrong result(?). Again, nothing to downvote.)

Answer (score 4):

$$\underbrace{e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x}_{\text{Euler's formula}}= \cosh(ix) + \sinh(ix)$$

You're mixing up the identities! To review, see [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

$$\begin{align} e^{ix} & = 1+(ix)+(ix)^2/2+ (ix)^3/3! + (ix)^4/4! + (ix)^5/5! + \cdots\\ \\ &  = 1 + i(x) - x^2/2 - i(x^3)/3! + x^4/4! + i(x^5)/5! +\cdots \\ \\
& = \left(1 - x^2/2 + x^4/4! +\cdots\right) + i\left(x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! + \cdots\right)\\ \\
& = \cos x + i\sin x\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! I mixed cosh with cos!

Comment: @amWHy: Could use another UV! +1